# Como hago para que se haga un numero finito de veces?

Tags: java, random

Estoy haciendo un programa con el que el ordenador elige un numero al azar y tu tienes que adivinar cual es, te va diciendo si es mayor o menos al numero que has introducido, pero quiero hacer que tenga un numero de intentos finitos, para que haya una opcion de que no ganes, el codigo es este, pero me falta lo de el numero finito de intentos(todas las variables esta, declaradas).

```
   adivino = (int) ((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
                do{
                 
                    System.out.println("INTENTO " +contador );
                    System.out.println("Introduzca un numero");
                    intento = entrada.nextInt();
                   
                    if (intento<adivino){
                        System.out.println("El numero a adivinar es MAYOR");
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("El numero a adivinar es MENOR");
                    } contador++;
                    
                    
                }while (intento != adivino);
                System.out.println("ENHORABUENA, HAS ACERTADO");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Agregar una variable para indicar el máximo de intentos
2. Usar esa variable en la condición del while
3. Agregar una rama al `if` de validación para el caso en el que `intento` es igual  a `adivino`. Si es igual usar `break` para terminar el bucle.

   ```
   adivino=(int)((Math.random()*100)+1);
   int maximo_intentos=5;
   do{

   System.out.println("INTENTO "+contador);
   System.out.println("Introduzca un numero");
   intento=entrada.nextInt();

   if(intento<adivino){
   System.out.println("El numero a adivinar es MAYOR");
   }else if(intento>adivino){
   System.out.println("El numero a adivinar es MENOR");
   }else{
   System.out.println("ENHORABUENA, HAS ACERTADO");
   break;
   }
   contador++;

   }while(intento<=maximo_intentos);
   System.out.println("PERDIO");
   ```